# In React how do I append a url from a database with https://

Tags: reactjs, url, https

I have this code in React:

```
{web  ? <p><a href={web} target="/blank" rel="noreferrer">{web}</a></p> : ''}
```

In my a tag I have an href pulling an URL from the database. However when I click the link in the application it goes to a local path because I'm missing the https part of the address. I've tried various option using a concatenating + but that still doesn't work

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: string concatenation isn't working? can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I just did href='https://' + {web} target..... but it didn't recognize the + symbol

Answer (score 4):

This should work.

```
{web && (
    <p>
        <a href={`https://${web}`} rel="noreferrer">
            {`https://${web}`}
        </a>
    </p>
)}
```

Comment: When I type in the code as you wrote, I get a parsing error saying a closing bracket is expected.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I missed back-ticks. I have fixed it now. You can try again.

Comment: That worked beautifully.  Thank you so much.